# no numeric data to plot

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, csv, matplotlib

У меня имеется csv файл
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

```
 A;B
0;-0,273
1;-0,039
2;0,049
3;0,264
4;0
5;-0,059
6;-0,254
7;0,039
8;0,039
9;0,234
10;-0,02
```

Необходимо построить график

Функция:

```
def grafic():
    try:
        plt.style.use('ggplot')  # графики
        plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15, 5)  # размер картинок
        file_name = fd.askopenfilename()
        f = open(file_name)

        fixed_df = pd.read_csv(file_name,
                               sep=';', encoding='latin1',
                                dayfirst=True,
                               index_col='A')


        fixed_df['B'].plot(figsize=(15, 10))
        f.close()
```

После выбора файла в приложении, выдаёт ошибку no numeric data to plot. Мол, нет чисел для вывода графика.. Почему нет то? Я перестаю понимать, прошу помощи! Может какую нибудь статью, либо литературу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pd.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) по умолчанию в качестве десятичной точки использует точку (`.`). Чтобы явно указать другой разделитель используйте параметр `decimal=","`:

```
file_name = r"C:\temp\test.csv"

fixed_df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=';', decimal=",", encoding='latin1')
#  NOTE: --------------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^

fixed_df["B"].plot(figsize=(15, 10))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: выдаёт  KeyError: 'A'

Comment: готово, изменил!

Comment: @is73dre, обратите внимание на пробел перед `A` - у вас имя столбца будет `" A"` (с пробелом)!

Comment: остаётся та же проблема

Comment: @is73dre, вы пробовали запустить измененный ответ?

Comment: конечно пробовал

Comment: @is73dre, интересно, что же я делаю не так и почему у меня все работает? ;) PS см. обновленный ответ с графиком

Comment: боже, я понял, всё, спасибо огромное, всё работает! С этим дипломным проектом голова уже окончательно поехала)))